# Array of abstract type subroutines - Fortran

Tags: oop, types, fortran, gfortran

Again I might have a weird question about how I would (or could) use types in Fortran.

Basically, what I hhave so far is an **abstract type** `AbsBase` with han interface. I can now extend this type multiple times bby defining **Child types** where I have different definitions of `sub` like so

#### Working example

---

**Base Module**

```
module BaseClass

    implicit none

    type, abstract :: AbsBase
    contains
        procedure(subInt), nopass, deferred :: sub
    end type

    interface
        subroutine subInt
            implicit none
        end subroutine subInt
    end interface

end module BaseClass
```

**Child Molude 1**

```
module ChildClass1

    use BaseClass 

    implicit noone

    type, extends(AbsBase) :: Child1
    contains
        procedure, nopass :: sub
    end type

contains

    subroutine sub
        implicit none
        print*, "Do something ..."
    end sub

end module ChildClass1
```

**Child Molude 2**

```
module ChildClass2

    use BaseClass 

    implicit noone

    type, extends(AbsBase) :: Child2
    contains
        procedure, nopass :: sub
    end type

contains

    subroutine sub
        implicit none
        print*, "Do something else ..."
    end sub

end module ChildClass2
```

**Program**

```
program test

    use ChhildClass1
    use ChhildClass2

    implicit none

    type(Child1) :: c1
    type(Child2) :: c2


    call c1%sub    ! <-- prints "Do something ...      "
    call c2%sub    ! <-- prints "Do somethhing else ..."

end program test
```

So far so good but what if I want to define an **array** of a type instead of having 2 different *Child* types? I have tried the following

#### Non-working example (what I try to do)

---

**Base Module**

```
module BaseClass

    implicit none

    type, abstract :: AbsBase
    contains
        procedure(subInt), nopass, deferred :: sub
    end type

    interface
        subroutine subInt
            implicit none
        end subroutine subInt
    end interface

    type :: BaseWrap
        class(AbsBase), pointer :: p
    end type

end module BaseClass
```

**Program**

```
program test

    use BaseClass

    implicit none

    type(BaseWrap) :: Child(2) 

    call Child(1)%p%sub   ! <--- This should produce "Do something ..."
    call Child(2)%p%sub   ! <--- This should produce "Do something else ..."

contains

    ! Where to I define the subroutines and how would I do this?

end module ChildClass
```

It actually compiles (which was quite surprising for me) but obviously results in a *Segmentation Fault* as I have nowhere defined the subroutines. If I understand right then I got with `type(BaseWrap) :: Child(2)` an array of pointers which point to the interface of the abstract type `AbsBase`. How would I now define the two subroutines from the *working example*? Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sorry, I don't understand how that would resolve my problem? Does this mean it is not possible what I'm trying to do?

Comment: No, you are actually already doing what is described there, I got confused by your type name Base, which is not actually the base for extending. It is what the link described as the wrapper.

Comment: But in that case I do not understand the question.  When you added the last part, what happened? When you actually allocate the pointers (although I would recommend allocatables), it should work just fine. You could also just have a procedure pointer in the Base class though and you could get rid of `AbsClass` altogether.

Comment: So, if I’m doing the right thing how would I be able to define my `sub` when using the *Base* type? I mean I can’t do something like `type, extend(Child(1)%p) :: c` and then define `sub` for every array index (Child(1), Child(2)).

Comment: The last part is just to clarify that I know how it can be done when I have an array. I’m not sure if that makes sense at all and I’m sorry if that is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I do not actually understand your main paragraph. Some terms are combined in a confusing way. What is an "interface of subroutines"? What is "override the subroutines by the array index"? Don't you just want to have an array of procedure pointers? Because otherwise I really do not understand what is your ultimate intention and I fear we are solving an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Hi! I have completely reformulated the question. I hope it makes more sense now! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the classes your created are just enough to have the polymorphic behaviour you seem to be looking for. You can test it like this:

```
program test
  use :: BaseClass
  implicit none

  type(Child1), target :: c1
  type(Child2), target :: c2
  type(BaseWrap) :: child(2)

  child(1)%p => c1
  child(2)%p => c2

  call child(1)%p%sub    ! <-- prints "Do something ...      "
  call child(2)%p%sub    ! <-- prints "Do somethhing else ..."
end
```

But using an `allocatable` element instead of `pointer` would remove the necesity of `target` attributes, among other advantages.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like this will answer my question. I will test this later on the day.

Answer (score 1):

Your design is good when those subroutines are somehow tight to the types, us their data and so on. You just need to define the pointers as Rodrigo showed. If those subroutines do not actually depend on any external type and the Child types are actually just made to hold a different procedure each, you don't need such a complex construction. You can just store the procedure pointers in a single type.

```
module subs
  implicit none

contains

    subroutine sub1
        print*, "Do something ..."
    end subroutine
    subroutine sub2
        print*, "Do something else ..."
    end subroutine
end module

  use subs

  type sub_wrap
    procedure(sub1), pointer, nopass :: sub
  end type

  type(sub_wrap) :: a(2)

  !one way
  a = [sub_wrap(sub1), sub_wrap(sub2)]

  !another way
!   a(1)%sub => sub1
!   a(2)%sub => sub2

  call a(1)%sub()
  call a(2)%sub()
end
```

Comment: @marc_s I do not really understand your edit. Why the participle instead of the present tense?